# .Net custom NuGet project package classes could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I made a simple custom NuGet project package with a few classes and have pulled it into a test project. It cant find the classes within that project.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found an alternative to the command line for creating NuGet package files. I used an addon called nuproj. Unfortunately it only works with VS2015 but it creates the .nuproj files for you without the need to use command line and create a nuspec file.